# How do I redirect to a parent directory in html

Tags: html, links

I want to know if it is possible (and how if it is) to Source to a Past Directory.

like say I have Index.html, Folder1 > page1.html inside Folder 1

Can I put a link in page1.html to reach backwards to send you to Index.html??? Im so tired of setting custom URLs to link to Index.html from the base domain...

My Project is here: [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/project/editor/ZpNdMM)

Comment: What server software you use?

Comment: Im using Codepen -_-

Comment: Im making a project, Im trying to create a link to send me back 1 directory to index.html https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/project/editor/ZpNdMM

Comment: Please note that HTML programming questions are off topic here.

Comment: @slhck Im confused, if html/website questions arent allowed here, Then why are tags and questions about html/websites so common. Also this question has already been answered, there is really no need for any more discussion here.

Comment: Please read the description of the HTML tag – it specifically mentions that fact. Also, just because the question is answered doesn't mean it's not off topic. I'm leaving the comment here so that you know what kind of questions to ask here in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use relative path in your web page
ex: `<a href="../file_name"></a>`

refer bellow site
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

To go up a folder:

```
<a href="../index.html">my link</a>
```

Comment: I know you CAN go backwards in directories, I forgot how to do it, Im sorry but this wont answer my question.

Comment: Are you trying to go up a folder? If so: <a href="../index.html">my link</a>.

Comment: THANKYOU.. yes! thats what I meant

Comment: Ok, I'll modify the answer :)

Comment: One more thing @raphael75 if I do like ../../index.html does that mean it will go backwards 2 directories? or is it like .../ or something?

Comment: Each ../ you add makes it go up another level in the folder structure. So to go up 2 levels, ../../myfile.html

Answer (score 1):

In the page1.html you could use relative paths:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="../index.html">Go up</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The link references the upper level in the File System hierarchy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but we already have an Answer, for future reference, try not to answer questions with a Green Fill on their tag, or the Check on an answer, as that means the question already has a definite answer, and Only answer in another case if you Know 100% that your answer is more efficient, better, or has more information the other didnt. Thankyou.

Comment: I realized I was editing my answer while Raphael was answering too... My mistake!